# bash - access all folders sequentially and run command

Tags: bash

I need a bash command that accesses (`cd`) all folders in the current directory sequentially and executes a command in each of the folders.

My problem is, I have circa 100 folders with similar Python scripts in them (all named `example.py`) and I want to execute all of them sequentially.

I'm thinking of something like this:

```
   for folder in directory:
       python example.py
```

Thank you for your interest.

Comment: I probably should have specified that the sample code is pseudocode used to illustrate what I wanted to do which is to access the folder, execute a python script, get back to the previous directory, access the subsequent folder and so on...

Comment: By access the folder I mean 'cd directory' and yes, there is a file called 'example.py' in each directory or 'folder'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for folder in */; do
    ( cd "$folder" && python example.py )
done
```

The trailing slash in `*/` makes sure we only match directory names. We use `( )` to start a subshell because `cd` only affects the current shell, so we don't have to `cd` back out in the parent shell.

Answer (score 0):

These kinds of tasks are usually handled by `find`, e.g. in your case:

```
find /path/to/top/dir -exec python example.py \;
```